# Cannot complete Gradle Build, failed linking references

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded a project with 3 modules, after trying to build it I get the following from gradlew assembleDebug--scan:

> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

The problem is, that as far as I can see, in a values.xml file in the build folder, meaning I can't change it. What am I doing wrong?.

```
>error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowBackground' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowBackground' not found., sources=[C:\Users\Charorfa\Downloads\atlas-contentcollector-forgroup\ATLASContentCollector\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:253], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

>error: style attribute '@android:attr/textColor' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute '@android:attr/textColor' not found., sources=[C:\Users\Charorfa\Downloads\atlas-contentcollector-forgroup\ATLASContentCollector\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:254], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

In sync it says

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018

but I think it is more of a warning, than an error.

I also found this, but I don't know if it can help me

[error: failed linking references. -> QueuedJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406186/error-failed-linking-references-queuedjob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you're trying using non-existent attribute for your style with:

```
@android:attr/windowBackground
```

and

```
@android:attr/textColor
```

Instead, you need to use `android:windowBackground` and `android:textColor` like in the following style:

```
  <style name="DontCopyMyStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, here is the problematic code:  

`    <style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="@android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
        <item name="@android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>`

Comment: remove the `@`, and use the attribute from my answer. So, it should be:    `<style name="dialog_light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item> <item name=android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item> </style>`

Comment: I cannot do that, the values.xml is on the build folder, it changes automatically

Comment: @Orcha: Check your `style.xml` in your resource directory (`res/`)