# Failed linking references - style attribute '@android:attr/textColor' not found in appcompat

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, android-styles

I'm trying to get rid of the soon-to-be-removed option `android.enableAapt2=false` from our project. It's been painful, but I hope I'm getting there.

Now I'm stuck with a `BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details`.

The issue seems to be this:

```
error: style attribute '@android:attr/textColor' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute '@android:attr/textColor' not found., 
sources=[/Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/4215c9c9bb2efc5bb086ff343ac44128/res/values/values.xml], 
original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

I've found the following question and answer, but I believe it's a bit different when it's not in our own project it's happening: [Cannot complete Gradle Build, failed linking references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683234/cannot-complete-gradle-build-failed-linking-references)

What's the reason for this happening and how can I solve it?

The specs:

> Android Studio 3.1.2
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
>   buildToolsVersion: 27.0.3
>   Gradle: 4.6
>   Gradle plugin: 3.1.2

**Edit:**
Just in case I removed every single line of styles and attributes from our project and did a clean build and invalidation of cache and restart and everything, but the build was still pointing its finger at the `values.xml` of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out that the main problem was that aapt2 did not report the problem location correctly.

Do a global search of all your style xml files for `name="@android`.
This is part of `<item name="@android:...`

You need to remove the @ character.

I have found this line in one of the files: `<item name="@android:textColor">#FF000000</item>`

aapt2 reported correctly issues with other locations where it found the @ character, but for some reason, it didn't report it correctly in this case.

You may need to search shared files or even library aar files if you have any.

Comment: Wow. That was actually the reason. We had a `<item name="@android:textColor">`. Removed the `@` and now everything just works. And I can start using Instant Run again. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Crazy... I was stuck on this for hours!